Error in invoking target 'all_no_orcl' of makefile 19c
I'm trying to install oracle 19c on oracle linux 9.4 , and getting this error:

Error in invoking target 'all_no_orcl' of makefile
'/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. See
'/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/InstallActions2024-07-03_05-16-47AM/installActions2024-07-03_05-16-47AM.log'
for details.


any suggestion please?
